# How can i change FutureBuilder to streambuilder what do i need to do here?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

After updating my profile with the edit page I have to refresh before I can see changes. Please can anyone help me change this code to a stream builder or at least tell me what to do??

```
createProfileTopView() {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: usersReference.document(widget.userProfileId).get(),
  builder: (context, dataSnapshot) {
    if (!dataSnapshot.hasData) {
      return circularProgress();
    } else {
      User user = User.fromDocument(dataSnapshot.data);
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
```

Answer (score 0):

The change must be made on the service, it will no longer return a Future, but must be a Stream.

As for the widget you should use the following, it is very similar to the FutureBuilder.

```html
return StreamBuilder
(
  stream: stream ,
  initialData: initialData ,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    return Container(
      child: child,
    );
  },
);
```

Good luck!